# Problemas con ventana modal y nav-tabs en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Estoy actualizando una web con html5,  Bootstrap, Php... etc... desde ya que es una web dinámica relacionada con el rubro inmobiliario, tras un clic en un botton, genero la apertura de una ventana MODAL la cual está compuesta de un header, body y footer; dentro del body inicio con un nav-tab de 3 pestañas.

El problema es que el contenido del `TABPANEL` es mas largo que el body y el footer juntos, los cuales no se adaptan a este largo, por lo cual estéticamente el contenido de la pestaña del `NAV-TAB` excede el tamaño de la ventana `MODAL` y estéticamente es horrible. ¿Alguna solución que puedan aportar?. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un contenedor en el body del modal y trabajar en css overflow.

Este sería el código:

```
/* Body del Modal */
<div class="wrapper">
...
...
...
</div>
```

en CSS

```
.wrapper {
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Bueno.... esta sirvio... no queda muy agradable pero por lo menos está todo el contenido dentro del body... Gracias.

Comment: Pero... ¿se puede hacer que no se muestre la barra lateral de movimiento?, eso sería genial!

Comment: Solucionado reemplace scroll x hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner una imagen de como se muestra tu modal o tu `html` para ver a qué te refieres: que es más largo el `body`. Y así poder responder mejor la pregunta.

Prueba también con el modal grande `class="modal-dialog modal-lg"` puede que se ajuste mejor tu tabpanel

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que buscaba era mas que nada alargar la ventana modal, con la sugerencia de Jorge Lodoño se soluciono, pero me muestra la barra de scroll y queda muy fea...